# What is the IUPAC name of perchloroisobutane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, halides

> What is the IUPAC name of $\ce{(CCl3)3CCl}?$

The answer I got was **1,1,1,2,3,3,3-heptachloro-2-(trichloromethyl)propane**. But when I looked up the question online, most sources say the answer is **2-(trichloromethyl)-1,1,1,2,3,3,3-heptachloropropane**, even though ‘chloro’ comes before ‘trichloromethyl’ alphabetically. What is the reason ‘chloro’ is written after ‘trichloromethyl’?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Chemdraw JS' Structure to Name feature which generally gives the PIN of the molecule, the PIN for $\ce{(CCl3)3CCl}$ is **1,1,1,2,3,3,3-heptachloro-2-(trichloromethyl)propane**

[image]

From *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-0-85404-182-4)*,

> **P-14.5** ALPHANUMERICAL ORDER
>
> Alphanumerical order has been commonly called ‘alphabetical order’. As these ordering principles do involve ordering both letters and numbers, in a strict sense, it is best called ‘alphanumerical order’ in order to convey the message that both letters and numbers are involved
>
> Alphanumerical order is used to establish the order of citation of detachable substituent prefixes (not the detachable saturation prefixes, hydro and dehydro), and the numbering of a chain, ring, or ring system when a choice is possible.
>
> (…)

> **P-14.5.1** Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically; multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

Here we have two main groups attached to $\ce{C-2}$, the (trichloromethyl) group and the (chloro) group.

> **P-14.5.2** The name of a prefix for a substituent is considered to begin with the first letter of its complete name.

Taking the example of 7-(2,4-dimethylpentyl)-5-ethyltridecane from the Blue Book, we see that in such a case, the di- is considered to be a part of the complete name and so needs to be considered as well.

Therefore the two names in the nomenclature of our compound would be 1,1,1,2,3,3,3-heptachloro and 2-trichloromethyl. Our parent chain is propane and so the PIN for the given compound becomes **1,1,1,2,3,3,3-heptachloro-2-(trichloromethyl)propane** which is the same name as suggested by Chemdraw JS.

Therefore, your proposed answer is correct and the source online is wrong when it comes to the PIN.